# XSD to validate same element name with different content

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I'm learning about XSDs. I wanted to know if there's a way to validate these 3 xml examples in one xsd? Let's just stick with XSD 1.0 (without asserts). I know I can technically use minOccurs=0 for all the sub elements. Is there a better solution?

```
<property>
    <item>car</item>
    <cost>500</cost>
    <wheels>4</wheels>
</property>

<property>
    <item>chair</item>
    <cost>100</cost>
    <legs>10</legs>
    <edible>yes</edible>
</property>

<property>
    <item>bed</item>
    <bedbugs>yes</bedbugs>
    <dirty>no</dirty>
</property>
```

Comment: *Is there a better solution?*........Define ***better***.

Comment: You can define all your specific elements as optional in your schema but that does not guarantee that all required elements are filled. other option could be to use a choice and define each specific property item as a sequence. But it is very difficult to give advice based on these random key value attributes that you've used in the example.